# scala compilation problem - with java libs

Tags: scala

Im trying to put together a simple ant build file for compiling a scala project (scala 2.7.6)...
I have everything working correctly except that its bringing up the
"fatal error: class java.lang.Object not found." both the scalac and scala libs are all in the project folder, so Im refering to them relativelly to the project root.

Im hoping that someone could help with which command line scalac option I can use to point the compiler towards the java core lib (if thats what it needs). Im hoping not to use any environemnt variables, and instead have the needed java libs in my project root folder...
that way I can have everything needed to compile movable with the project, and not need any setup for others to be able to compile

thank you

Comment: Can you list the jar files in your project folder?  maybe there's something there that shouldn't be.  You should set your classpath to (LIBDIR/*) if you're runnning scalac from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Scala 2.7.6 is a broken release.
Please upgrade to 2.7.7

Also, do you have javac on PATH and JAVA_HOME set?

Comment: I just moved to 2.7.7 and unfortunately it doesnt fix the problem
I have both of those variables set correctly
tried calling javac by hand, works
JAVA_HOME set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun, on ubuntu8.04

thanks